# Problemas para pintar emojis en R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hola espero me puedan ayudar.

Estoy Realizando unas practicas en R haciendo estadística de mensajes de whatsapp. Ocupo la biblioteca `library("rwhatsapp")` y pasa algo realmente Raro, durante el código si puedo escribir emojis `chat <- rwa_read("/Users/fernandoestrada/Documents/Experimentos/Chat de WhatsApp con  Evelyn.txt")` y quiero hacer un top de emojis, para ello hago lo siguiente:

```
library("tidyr")
chat %>%
  unnest(emoji) %>%
  count(author, emoji, sort = TRUE) %>%
  group_by(author) %>%
  top_n(n = 6, n) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = reorder(emoji, n), y = n, fill = author)) +
  geom_col(show.legend = FALSE) +
  ylab("") +
  xlab("") +
  coord_flip() +
  facet_wrap(~author, ncol = 2, scales = "free_y")  +
  ggtitle("Most often used emojis")
```

El problema es que no se ven los emojis en los titulos a la hora de hacer el plot ¿Alguien sabe por qué? estoy pensando que me hace falta alguna libreria.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]